# i want to redraw on a view Android programming

Tags: android, android-graphview

I am creating an app that displays the graphs of input given by a user. The graph is drawn on a linear layout using some library..i want the linear layout to redraw the new function requested by the user everytime the user clicks the draw button..I have tried using layout.invalidate() but this is not working in my app.please help ..below is code snipet :

```
bb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
 public void onClick(View v)
    {
       String text = ee.getText().toString(); // getting the user expression input
       LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph2);
       layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

       Expression data = Expression.createExpression(text) ;

       if(text == ""){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please enter a valid equation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           }
       else
           { 
               draw(data) ; 
               layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               layout.invalidate();
           }                                                       
         } 
       });

public void draw(Expression x)
    {
        final GraphView graphing = new LineGraphView(this, "sketch");
        int num = 350;
        GraphViewData[] array = new GraphViewData[num];
        double w=0;
        for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
           w += 0.2;
           array[i] = new GraphViewData(i, x.evaluate(w,0,0));  }


        // add data
        graphing.addSeries(new GraphViewSeries(array));
        // set view port, start=2, size=40
        graphing.setViewPort(0, 120);
        graphing.getGraphViewStyle().setNumHorizontalLabels(2);
        graphing.setScrollable(true);
        // optional - activate scaling / zooming
        graphing.setScalable(true);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph2);
        layout.addView(graphing);
        layout.invalidate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
graphing.setViewPort(0, 120);
```

is it correct? To me it looks like you set view width to 0.

Next, you sure you don't want to discard old results by removing old views from layout?

Last, layout auto-invalidated when you add or remove child views.